# Eclipse: High CPU usage while building the project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), an my OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have some problems with any project build in eclipse, when building is at ~80% progress, CPU usage reaches even 300% and the IDE get freeezed or some Errors/Exceptions are thrown (GC overhead, OutOfMemory, etc). The project is huge, but for the same project it had been working ok until a few days ago. My eclipse .ini is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1048m
-Xmx4048m
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change anything in the last few days?

Comment: No, I do not added any new plugins or something like that. When I noticed that it moves slower and slower, I made an update to Eclipse Mars.2 Release (before that I had been using Mars1) but nothing has changed since then. I also try to use another workspace but it has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and not 16.04 LTS? Because in Ubuntu 16.04 this is a known issue:

In your *eclipse.ini* file you could add

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before `-vmargs` (see [Ubuntu bug #1552764](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764)).

But the better solution would be to use [Eclipse Neon](http://eclipse.org/neon) which solves this issue and which has been released on Wednesday.

Comment: Turned out I was searching for high CPU usage on Neon!